# Substitution function for Lambda expression

Tags: function, haskell, lambda, substitution

I am currently writing the function and I am unable to get around the 4th case and that is:

> (E1 E2)[v->E] = E1[v->E] E2[v -> E]

I have already defined the first 3(for a constant and variable) but this turns out to be little too tricky for me.

However, the function signature is:

```
sub :: LExpr -> String -> LExpr -> LExpr
```

I am confused first how to represent the argument `(E1 E2)` and later how to do the `E1[v->E] E2[v -> E]`-part. I think `++` doesn`t work here because the outcome must be lambda expression and not String.

The definition of `data LExpr` is the "common" one for Haskell and uses `Eq` and `Show`. If needed I can provide it, but it is pretty basic and you must be well acquainted with it.

Comment: please don't hesitate to show us your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the definition is simply a rewriting of

```
(E1 E2)[v->E] = E1[v->E] E2[v -> E]
```

into Haskell syntax. First we use `sub` instead of the `[v -> E]` notation.

```
sub (E1 E2) v E = (sub E1 v E) (sub E2 v E)
```

Then we make syntactic application between `LExpr`s explicit.

```
sub (App E1 E2) v E = App (sub E1 v E) (sub E2 v E)
```

Finally, we use lowercase names for variables, since Haskell reserves uppercase ones for constructors.

```
sub (App e1 e2) v e = App (sub e1 v e) (sub e2 v e)
```

Comment: but of course I must have used application... Thanks!!